# Setting queueSize parameter for ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender

Tags: asynchronous, queue, parameter-passing, logback

I need to organize asynchronous logging in java via logback. `AsyncAppender` class is used, which has a parameter named `queueSize`. That parameter affects the number of log messages of level INFO and less, that will be discarded, when queue's threshold is reached.

I need to understand how it is possible to set `queueSize` via `logback.xml`. I searched a lot, in manual, documentation and in google, but it didn't help.

Here is a small part of my `logback.xml`:

```
<appender name="async_tempLog" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
      <appender-ref ref="tempLog" />  
</appender>
```

If there is no way to do it via `logback.xml`, please show how to do it in java? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>262144</queueSize>
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    <appender-ref ref="tempLog" />
</appender>
```

Comment: How queue size value 262144 is arrived to this..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar 2^18=262144. I don't think it is necessary or even beneficial to set the queue size to a multiple of 2, but it never hurts. The size was not given in the question, so eagerToLearn just chose some value.